# <p:calendar> highlight specific dates (values from bean)

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, calendar

Using the primefaces `<p:calendar>` component, I need to highlight certain dates.
I am aware of its `beforeShowDate` attribute, but the dates to be highlighted need to be fetched from the backing bean.

Using a `<h:inputHidden value="#{bean.theDates}" />` results in a single String value containing comma separated Date Strings.

**How can I set a styleClass for a given list of dates (in my bean)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an EL expression to output the dates from your bean as an array in your `beforeShowDay` JavaScript function. The function should check if the date is in your array, if it is set the correct CSS class in the returned array.

The output of `#{bean.theDates}` could be `['2014-01-01','2014-02-01']`, and your JavaScript function would look something like this:

JavaScript in head of page:

```
<script>
    function highlightDays(date) {
        var dates = #{bean.theDates};
        var cssclass = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
            if (date === new Date(dates[i])) {
               cssclass = 'mycss';
            }
        }
        return [true, cssclass];
    }
</script>
```

PrimeFaces Calendar:

```
<p:calendar beforeShowDate="highlightDays" />
```

Comment: thanks, did not know that EL can be used that simply withing JS. 

Works like a charm after manually creating a JS-Date-Array compatible String within the bean. A `Collection<Date>` did not work out of the box.