# Primeface's scheduler. How to change the background color of weekend day using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsf, primefaces

This is a question related to the scheduler object of Primefaces. I want to change the css of the scheduler object but I do not know how to do. I have searched everywhere in the internet but I am not manage to find the answer.

In my country, the majority race is Muslim. We have 13 states and they can be divided into two:

1) States which have Friday and Saturday as weekend.

2) States which have Saturday and Sunday as weekend. (This is like what happens in America)

I have added a drop-down for state.

If user selects #1, there will be new background colour in the column of Friday and Saturday.
If user selects #2, there will be new background colour in the colomn of Saturday and Sunday.

Can I know how to achieve this? Thank you.

Jimmy

Comment: There is some nice example ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630795/pcalendar-highlight-specific-dates-values-from-bean

Comment: i think ur example has just answered this. Thank you. I shall check this later.

Comment: p:calendar (in the link) != p:schedule